# How to get complete SID from the SidStart member in a pointer that points to an ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE structure?

Tags: c++, pointers, winapi, memory, sid

Starting with a string variable containing a [Security Descriptor String Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/security-descriptor-string-format), I convert this string to a security descriptor (using [ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptorW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sddl/nf-sddl-convertstringsecuritydescriptortosecuritydescriptorw) function).

This function gives me a "pointer" to a Security Descriptor (I put the pointer under quotation mark relative to [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20151223-00/?p=92701)).

Next, I recover a pointer to the DACL of the pointed Security Descriptor using [GetSecurityDescriptorDacl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-getsecuritydescriptordacl) function. From this DACL, I store all the ACEs into a vector of pointers to [ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-access_allowed_ace) structures. Finally in these structures, there is my targeted member (**SidStart**) that I want to use to get a "translation" of the SID (for example with [Well-Known SIDs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/well-known-sids), I want to translate "S-1-1-0" to a final user readable string like "Everyone").

However, SidStart only gives the first DWORD of a trustee's SID. The remaining bytes of the SID are stored in contiguous memory after the SidStart member (as [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-access_allowed_ace) said). Despite my researches over the Internet, I can't figure it out to get theses remaining bytes.

Here is a minimum reproducible example in a C++ Console App:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <sddl.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    LPCWSTR stringSecurityDescriptor = L"D:AI(D;OICI;DCLCDTSD;;;S-1-1-0)";
    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSD;
    ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptorW(stringSecurityDescriptor, SDDL_REVISION_1, &pSD, nullptr);

    PACL pDacl;
    BOOL bDaclPresent = SE_DACL_PRESENT;
    BOOL bDaclDefaulted = SE_DACL_DEFAULTED;
    GetSecurityDescriptorDacl(pSD, &bDaclPresent, &pDacl, &bDaclDefaulted);

    LPVOID pAce;
    ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE* pAceBuffer;
    vector<ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE*> pDaclAces;

    if (bDaclPresent)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < pDacl->AceCount; i++)
        {
            GetAce(pDacl, i, &pAce);

            pAceBuffer = (ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE*)pAce;
            pDaclAces.push_back(pAceBuffer);
        }
    }
    
    /* TODO : Get the SID of the ACEs */
}
```

I'm relatively new in C++ programming (and in programming in general), particularly in winapi environment. Moreover, this is my first question on StackOverflow. So, I hope my question is clear, understandable and resolvable. I'm open to critics.

Comment: use `(PSID)&SidStart`

Comment: Wonderful @RbMm, I applied it to my solution and it worked properly. Many thanks !

Comment: in most general case - https://github.com/rbmm/NtRegView/blob/master/security.cpp#L268

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @RbMm in the comment section of my question :

> use (PSID)&SidStart

I've added this line to my project (by replacing the TODO section in the minimum reproducible example) in order to test it :

```
PSID pSid = (PSID)&pDaclAces[0]->SidStart
```

And then I converted it into a readable string by reusing and readapting [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/finding-the-owner-of-a-file-object-in-c--) with Microsoft documentation to my case, and all of it worked perfectly.